# How to create a Yocto recipe for cmake with separate -dev package of header files?

Tags: cmake, yocto

I am trying to write a Yocto recipe for an in-house library that uses cmake to build and install itself. Running `make install` from the command line, the library installs the following files (headers are somewhat abridged):

```
-- Installing: /prefix/lib/libreflection.so
-- Installing: /prefix/lib/libreflection.a
-- Installing: /prefix/include/reflect
-- Installing: /prefix/include/reflect/type.h
-- Installing: /prefix/include/reflect/detail
-- Installing: /prefix/include/reflect/detail/type.h
-- Installing: /prefix/include/reflect/detail/property.h
-- Installing: /prefix/include/reflect/detail/iterator
-- Installing: /prefix/include/reflect/detail/iterator/range.h
-- Installing: /prefix/include/reflect/detail/accessor.h
-- Installing: /prefix/include/reflect/property.h
-- Installing: /prefix/include/reflect/register.h
-- Installing: /prefix/include/reflect/object.h
-- Installing: /prefix/lib/cmake/libreflection/libreflection-config.cmake
-- Installing: /prefix/lib/cmake/libreflection/libreflection-config-noconfig.cmake
```

I would like to differentiate between a binary ".so only" Yocto package (`libreflection`) and a development version that additionally includes the static library, header and cmake package files (`libreflection-dev`).

My initial recipe is as follows, but with it both `libreflection` and `libreflection-dev` package all files:

```
DESCRIPTION = "C++ reflection library"
SECTION = "libs"
LICENSE = "CLOSED"

SRCREV = "${AUTOREV}"
SRCBRANCH = "master"
SRC_URI = "git://gitlab.company.com/group/${PN}.git;branch=${SRCBRANCH};protocol=ssh"

inherit cmake

S = "${WORKDIR}/git"

FILES_${PN}-dev += "${libdir}/cmake"

# The following are needed because the library is unversioned.
# See https://wiki.yoctoproject.org/wiki/TipsAndTricks/Packaging_Prebuilt_Libraries#Non-versioned_Libraries
SOLIBS = ".so"
FILES_SOLIBSDEV = ""
```

I have tried various changes to the `FILES_${PN}*` variables, but none have achieved the desired effect. Generally I either end up with packaging errors, or both `libreflection` and `libreflection-dev` include all files.

How can I adjust the recipe such that `libreflection` includes only the `.so`, and `libreflection-dev` includes all the files?

Comment: Did you you that [section](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#including-static-library-files)? You should try to add `FILES_${PN}-dev += "${libdir}/lib*.a"` but usually static libs are in `-staticdev` package.